# How can I get the time from MySql in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, time

I have a column in my table that contains a time data type. I need to print it's value. Here is the code that I am using:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
System.out.print("\t\t"+rs.getTime("Total Time"));
```

The output is 00:00:00, but the actual value in my database is 24:00:00. How can I get the right value?

Comment: You aren't calling [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) before `getTime()`?

Comment: Strange, I would bet that 24:00:00 is the same as 00:00:00. With the only difference that the 24 notation is invalid. But I don't know these computers...

Comment: @jarekczek if you use just rs.getTime() it'd return 00:00 for 24:00 hrs, you can format it using simpledateformat.format("kk:mm:ss") method to return 24:00 for 00:00..check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Call [`rs.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) before using `getTime()` in order to move the cursor forward to the *first* row:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
if (rs.next()) {
  System.out.print("\t\t"+rs.getTime("Total Time"));
}
```

From the documentation:

> A `ResultSet` cursor is **initially** positioned **before the first row**; the
>   first call to the method `next` **makes the first row the current row**; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

Comment: The odd thing is that it should be throwing an exception from `getTime(...)` without that call to `next()`, but it sounds like it's returning an actual value...

Answer (score 1):

u are missing **rs.next()** before you print.

**To print 24:00:**
rs.getTime will return Time object with format `"HH:mm"` `(00:00 to 23:00)`. if you want the time from `(01:00-24:00)` format the time using `simpledateformat("kk:mm").format()` method like below.

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
while(rs.next()) { // if resutset not empty
    System.out.println(new   SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss").format(rs.getTime("time").getTime())); //
```

}

check the [ResultSet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for more information :)